# RHEL linker error

Tags: linux, rhel

I am on `RHEL 5.8` on `x86_64` machine:

```
$ uname -r
2.6.18-308.1.1.el5
$ uname -m
x86_64
$
```

try to cross-compile the sources to be the `i386` compatible:

```
CFLAGS += -m32
LDFLAGS += -L/lib -lpthread -luuid
```

but link stage fails with error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libuuid.so when searching for -luuid
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libuuid.a when searching for -luuid
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -luuid
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Actually, the host machine has the `/lib/libuuid.so.1.2`:

```
$ readelf -h /lib/libuuid.so.1.2
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0xf90
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          13352 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         6
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         28
  Section header string table index: 27
$
```

Are there any `ld` or other's options to fix this link issue?

Comment: Do you also have a `libuuid.so -> libuuid.so.1.2` symlink in /lib?

Comment: I have created the link and the binary compiled ok! Could you please post the answer? I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linker only searches for the library name, without version numbers ("libuuid.so"). The convention is to symlink that to the `soname` (which would be "libuuid.so.1" in this case), which in turn is a symlink to the real shared library (in this case "libuuid.so.1.2").

So, you'll need these symlinks in `/lib` for the linker to find the library.

(more on this topic: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to link against a specific shared object then you must pass it directly to the compiler or linker.